# How to calculate bearing loads in a two stage helical gear box?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears, applied-mechanics, bearings

[image: HELICAL 2 STAGE GEAR ARRANGEMENT]

Here P, Q, R, S are the bearings and G1, G2, G3, G4 are four helical gears.
The gear forces tangential(Kp), Axial(Ka), Radial(Kn) are known.
All the distances are known. The forces acting on bearing are radial on non locating bearing and both radial and axial on locating bearing.  P, R are non locating bearings. Q, S are locating bearings.. Fh and Fv are components of radial force on bearings and Fa is the axial force... How to calculate Fh, Fv and Fa for each bearing shown??

I have calculated all the gear forces but i am confused about the calculation of the forces. will be solved using moment equations?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should show what you have attempted so far, so people can edit or improve your work. Please note this is not a free design service, if you have not taken the tour please do.